# Grails async task not loading saved data

Tags: grails, asynchronous

Saved data doesn't seem available to the thread that is running in a task unless it is also wrapped in a task (grails 2.3.1). The base test case is as follows, with the result being the count outside the task is 1 and 0 inside the task. How do I avoid having all data saving operations wrapped in tasks?

```
@Test
void testMemberSync() {
    String inputMemberData = """{"startMemberNumber" : "1002016", "endMemberNumber" : "",   "memberData": [
        {"membershipNumber":"1002016","key": "1111",  "surname":"tester","forenames":"John","preferredEmail":"jrobens+1777@interlated.com.au","tags": [" """ + CollaborationCategoryEnum.FED_REP.toString() + """ "]},
]}"""

    JSONObject memberParamData = (JSONObject) JSON.parse(inputMemberData)

    memberParamData.memberData.each { member ->
        new MemberUpdateCache(member)
    }

    assert Member.count > 0

    Promise memberDeleteDeltas = task {
        println "Member count in promise is : ${Member.count()}"
        assert Member.count > 0
    }
    memberDeleteDeltas.onError { Throwable err ->
        throw new Exception("task threw error")
    }
}
```

MemberUpdateCache just calls new Member:

```
public MemberUpdateCache(JSONObject jsonMember) {
  Member newMember = new Member(key: jsonMember.key,
            membershipNumber: jsonMember.membershipNumber,
            surname: jsonMember?.surname,
            forenames: civiForenames,
            preferredEmail: jsonMember?.preferredEmail
    )
    newMember.save(failOnError: true)
}
```

I can't get the test case to work by wrapping the creation with withNewSession() or withTransaction(). "flush:true" also doesn't work.

Wrapping the creation in another task does work:

```
Promise createMemberPromise = task {
        Member.withTransaction { status ->
            memberParamData.memberData.each { member ->
                new MemberUpdateCache(member)
            }
        }
    }
    waitAll createMemberPromise

    assert Member.count > 0
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping the creation in another task works. May cause errors - but I haven't found another answer. Everything data related therefore needs a task.

```
Promise createMemberPromise = task {
    Member.withTransaction { status ->
        memberParamData.memberData.each { member ->
            new MemberUpdateCache(member)
        }
    }
}
waitAll createMemberPromise

assert Member.count > 0
```